# maximum and maximal elements

Tags: order-theory

Let B = {(2,4), (4,0), (4,3), (7,3)}. B has the order like the product order of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ . Then, why B hasn't maximum and why the maximal elements are (2,4) and (7,3)?

Comment: With the definitions of maximum and maximal I don't know how apply this results for understanding this solution.

Comment: Do you know the definitions?  If so, state them, as there are quite possibly multiple definitions out there.

Comment: I know the following definitions:

Comment: I know the following definitions:

$\times \in X$ is maximal if $\not \exists y \in X / x \leq y , x \neq y$

$\times \in X$ is maximum if $\forall y \in X / y \leq x$

But I don't know how apply it in my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product order (meaning $(a,b) \leq (c,d)$ iff $a \leq c$ and $b \leq d$) gives the following cover relations for $B$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
(4,0) &\leq& (4,3) \\
(4,3) &\leq& (7,3) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

So the maximal elements are $(2,4)$ and $(7,3)$. E.g. $(2,4)$ is maximal because there is no element $(a,b) \in B$ such that $(2,4) \leq (a,b)$.

There is no maximum because none of the elements is such that all other elements are $\leq$ it. E.g. $(2,4)$ is maximal - but it is not a maximum because, for example, $(7,3) \not\leq (2,4)$.